# Meteor.js collection: new record not updating in bootstrap ui popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a "Messages" collection that I'm displaying via an {{#each}} in a bootstrap ui popover.  For some reason, when I

```
Messages.find({});
```

In the console, I can see the new record... but the popover does not show the record unless I close it and then reopen.

Here is the template which calls the overlay:

```
<template name="messages">
  <div class="container section-light">
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        </div>
        <div class="display-name col-xs-10">
          <a class="display-name-link display-name-link-{{this._id}}" data-toggle="popover" href="#">{{displayName}}</a>
          <div id="popover-content-{{this._id}}" class="friend-message hide container">
            <div class="message-list">
              {{#each messages }}
                <div class="message-item">
                  <p class="message">{{message}}</p>
                </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Need a lot more code to see where the issue is! At very least the template event that fires the popover.

Comment: @jorjordandan what about at the most? I'll start with the template, but I'd like to give you any other information you might find relevant.

Comment: The fact that it's there the second time means that it's almost certainly due to the publication not being ready in time. Any relevant js for the view? like a `Template.messages.events` or anything? At the most, you could create a meteorpad repro (http://meteorpad.com) since you asked...

Comment: @jorjordandan if I place the each outside of s bootstrap overlay, it works as expected. Is there some way to force a redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the Bootstrap popover generates a new DOM object and inserts it every time the popover is opened. This means that although you are updating the info that should be in it, bootstrap has already generated the popover, so the new entries won't show up. In your `template.onRendered` you could track messages being added with something like:

```
count = Messages.find().count();

this.autorun(function(){

  if (Messages.find().count() > count){ //check if messages added since dom loaded
     if($('.popover')){ //check if a popover is currently open..
        //identify popover and re-trigger it...
     }
  }
});
```

Because this is such a pain, if I were you I would just write my own popover that uses a hidden element and then shows it when triggered, instead of adding new dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the template with `Template.subscriptionsReady` to ensure that the subscriptions are ready as shown below. [Reference](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe).

```
<template name="messages">
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  <div class="container section-light">
    <li>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        </div>
        <div class="display-name col-xs-10">
          <a class="display-name-link display-name-link-{{this._id}}" data-toggle="popover" href="#">{{displayName}}</a>
          <div id="popover-content-{{this._id}}" class="friend-message hide container">
            <div class="message-list">
              {{#each messages }}
                <div class="message-item">
                  <p class="message">{{message}}</p>
                </div>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: No luck. If I place the each somewhere outside of a bootstrap-ui overlay though, the reactiveness works as expected